# Change button text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table which I want to hide or show on the click of a button. Also, when the button is clicked, its text should be changed appropriately. I have the following code, but the button's text is not being changed:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myButton").click(function () {
                $(".myTable").toggle(1000, "linear", function changeButtonText() {
                    $("#myButton").text = ($("#myButton").text === "Hide table" ? "Show table" : "Hide table");
                });
            });
        });
</script>

... 

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Hide table" />
<table class="myTable">
    ...
</table>
```

Comment: It should be `$("#myButton").text()` not just `$("#myButton").text`

Comment: `.text()` is function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myButton").val($("#myButton").val() === "Hide table" ? "Show table" : "Hide table");
```

Comment: No it's not, mine works. `$("#myButton").val(...)`, you have `$("#myButton").val() = ...`.

Comment: @Waxi maybe you didn't see my answer ^^

Comment: @Ionut You set the value by passing it INTO the `val()` method, not by assigning a value TO the `val()` method.

Comment: @Waxi thanks for clarifying, he has a hard time understanding :)

Comment: @Arg0n Thanks. This is indeed the only working answer.

Comment: @Ionut Which basically makes your answer a copy of mine.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't use the function in the right way:

---

- If the element is **button**:

Error:

```
$("#myButton").text = ("new text");
```

Work:

```
$("#myButton").text("new text");
```

Working example:

```js
$("#myButton").text("New text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="myButton">Old text</button>
```

---

- If the element is **input type="button"**:

Error:

```
$("#myButton").text = ("new text");
```

Work:

```
$("#myButton").val("new text");
```

Working example:

```js
$("#myButton").val("New text");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Hide table" />
```

Comment: It's an `input` tag and not `button`

Answer (score 2):

use this to change the text of your button

```
$("#myButton").attr('value', 'newText');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to tweak your code and worked for me.You have to pass the vale like `$("#myButton").val(Buttontext);`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $(".myTable").toggle(1000, "linear", function changeButtonText() {

    var text= ($("#myButton").val() === "Hide table" ? "Show table" : "Hide table");
    $("#myButton").val(text);
    });
  });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/w34wfn92/) work for me

Answer (score 0):

you can use if statement to check the value of your button but first you must get the attribute which is value.

```
$("#myButton").click(function () {
    $(".myTable").toggle(1000, "linear", function changeButtonText() {
        var text = $("#myButton").attr("value");
      if(text == "Hide table") {
        $("#myButton").attr("value","Show table");
      }
      else {
        $("#myButton").attr("value","Hide table");
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


... 

<button id="myButton">Hide table</button>
<table class="myTable">
    <tr><td>works</td></tr>
</table>
<script>
            $("#myButton").click(function () {
            
                if($("#myButton").text() == "Hide table") { 
                  $(".myTable").hide();
                  $("#myButton").text("Show table");
                } 
                else {
                  $(".myTable").show();
                  $("#myButton").text("Hide table");
                }
                
            });
    </script>
```

Put the javascript at the bottom of your body delete the ready function this works for me